# How to convert an array of objects to a string you can use with document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What I need is to be able to call on an Array, like this: "myArray[0]" and have the Object in that position come out as a readable string. Here is my code. The alert just says "object Object" - but you can't read it.

```
var test = [myObject = {name: 'tristyn', 
                bed: 'felicity',
                quote: '$1,000'
                       },
    myObject2 = {name: 'tristyn', 
                bed: 'felicity',
                quote: '$1,000'
                       }
           ];
alert(test[0]);
```

Comment: How does this relate to `.getElementByID()`? The properties of the objects shown don't seem to be element IDs... `test[0].name` would give you `'tristyn'`, and `test[1].quote` would give `'$1,000'`.

Comment: What does this have to do with `getElementById`?

Comment: There is no DOM element represented by `myObject` (also, don't do assignments within expressions). Don't bring GEBI into this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the desired output string (a "readable string" is too vague a description), and to explain what this has to do with `.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2):

Please use [`JSON.stringify(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in order to convert an object to it's string representation. Keep in mind that only basic types will be serialized (for example, functions can't be serialized to JSON): numbers, strings, arrays, objects and nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var test = [myObject = {name: 'tristyn', 
                bed: 'felicity',
                quote: '$1,000'
                       },
    myObject2 = {name: 'tristyn', 
                bed: 'felicity',
                quote: '$1,000'
                       }
           ];
alert(JSON.stringify(test[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this long hand method.

```js
var test = [
      myObject = {
        name: 'tristyn', 
        bed: 'felicity',
        quote: '$1,000'
      },
      myObject2 = {name: 'tristyn', 
        bed: 'felicity',
        quote: '$1,000'
      }
];
    
var string = "";
    
for (var i in test[0])
  string += i + ": " + test[0][i] + "\n";
    
alert(string);
```

You can replace the colon (':') and "\n" with any text you like.